# Brownian Motion/Ito Integral Variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

[image]

So I am somewhat confused about the entire derivation of the variance of Qn(T) but if someone could explain the steps taken to derive the MGFs I feel like that would allow me to figure it out.

Comment: $Q_n (T)$ is the quadratic variation sampled at intervals of size $\Delta$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.